Tp-Link Powerline drops sync when device on network connects to VPN
I have a main router using WDSL in my home and I have a Raspberry PI at outside that I needed internet for it for some automated tasks it does.
Since there was no easy way of bringing internet to there, I used TP-Link Powerline TL-WPA4220KIT.
It worked OK until few days ago when I tried to connect the Raspberry to my VPN server that I host on somewhere else on internet. I setup the VPN client to the RPI and made the service enabled. It connected pretty OK and everything was good, then the next day I noticed that powerline light on the TPLink adapter was off but wifi was still there, so I was able to connect to the powerline router but without having internet. I restarted them and re-sync, it started to work again but after few minutes it droped again the sync. I tried shutting them down for hours and reset both of them etc but no way they were keep losing the sync between.
Then I disabled the service on RPI and also stopped the openvpn client connection to VPN server and everything started to work again without dropping the sync.
I'm good on server and software side but on hardware and networking I don't have too much knowledge to know what might be causing the issue. But it's not making too much sense either.
I just noticed that the both adapters are a bit hot and I'm thinking maybe VPN connecting keeps handshaking and transferring data makes it overwhelm and causes to drop sync? Because it's summer here now with 35 celcious degree even in the house.
Anyone has experience anything like this? Or do you have any idea what might be the cause? I honestly not need too much from this powerline but my RPI needs internet on start if it restarts to fetch time and then start the other services that relys on time. VPN was just for me to be able to monitor from remote.
Update: I was thinking it was due to VPN because when I dropped VPN for few Hours it didn't drop but finally it did drop again without VPN.
Values from plcstat
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo plcstat -i wlan0 -t
 P/L NET TEI ------ MAC ------ ------ BDA ------  TX  RX CHIPSET FIRMWARE
 LOC CCO 001 D8:0D:17:9E:99:1B D8:3A:DD:C1:19:D5 n/a n/a QCA7420 MAC-QCA7420-1.3.1.2141-00-20160428-CS
 REM STA 002 34:E8:94:63:61:5E 48:8F:5A:FC:68:43 209 245 QCA7420 MAC-QCA7420-1.3.1.2141-00-20160428-CS
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo plcstat -i wlan0 -d both -s CSMA-ALL
   DIR ----------- PBs PASS ----------- PBs FAIL PBs ERR ---------- MPDU ACKD ---------- MPDU FAIL
    TX                  308                   59  16.08%                  310                    0                   11   0.00%
    RX                 2658                  469  15.00%                 1437                    0   0.00%

   PHY ----------- PBs PASS ----------- PBs FAIL PBs ERR ----------- BER PASS ----------- BER FAIL BER ERR
 0 222                  341                  202  37.20%                19867                50976  71.96%
 1 244                  333                  127  27.61%                20502                29388  58.91%
 2 253                  395                   40   9.20%                25202                 6347  20.12%
 3 244                  403                   35   7.99%                25996                 5273  16.86%
 4 238                  444                   21   4.52%                31876                 1909   5.65%
 5 235                  433                   29   6.28%                35946                 3380   8.59%
   ALL                 2658                  469  15.00%               179776                99185  35.56%   2.14%


What link speed do the adapters normally report? plcstat -i eth0 -t from open-plc-tools should show it; it doesn't say much but is at least a very rough indication of what the link quality is like. (plcstat -i eth0 -d both -s CSMA-ALL might get more stats, might be worth looking at the "BER ERR%" numbers.)

Sorry I need to update the question because I thought it was VPN but looks like VPN just makes it drop faster, it still drops without VPN. I'll now check what you've asked me to run.

updated the question with the commands you provided as it's too long to paste here.
